# Returning a value to caller via chain of methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, return, return-value

Say I call a method. I want a return value from that method. However, this method delegates tasks to other methods, which in turn may delegate tasks to other methods still. The value that gets eventually returned by the top most method is ultimately determined by the submethods, and the submethods' submethods.

Imagine this scenario:

```
 public String method1(Object o){

if(x)
return subMethod1(o);
if(y)
return subMethod2(o);
if(z)
return subMethod3(o);
else
return "";

}
```

//example submethod

```
public String subMethod1(Object o){

if(a)
return subSubMethod1(o);
if(b)
return subSubMethod2(o);
if(c)
return subSubMethod3(o);
else
return "";

}
```

//example subsubmethod

```
public String subSubMethod1(Object o){

//etc etc

return "";

}
```

This a reoccurring problem for me, and I am hoping there is a design pattern to solve this type of problem.

Is there such a design pattern?

Answer (score 6):

If you *really* want to go with a design pattern, Chain of Responsibility is the closest pattern I can think of for your situation.  But this can go overboard very quickly

```
public interface Handler{

     void setNext(Handler h);

     String handle(Object o);
}


public class Method1Handler implements Handler{
   private Handler next;

   @Override
   public void setNext(Handler h){
       this.next= h;
   }

   @Override
   public String handle(Object o){
      if(x){
         return subMethod1();
      }else if(next !=null){
         return next.handle(o);
      }
      return "";

   }

}
```

Of course `subMethod1()` would also use CoR etc.  It could get pretty ugly but the top level is clean:

```
 //top level of code
 Method1Handler handler = new Method1Handler();
 //...lots of set next
 //...and set next of nexts etc
 //...
 return myHandler.handle(o);
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator makes each set of choices simple - and if you lay it out correctly, it's really easy to read, once you've got the hang of the pattern:

```
return x ? subMethod1(o)
     : y ? subMethod2(o)
     : z ? subMethod3(o)
     : "";
```

Of course, if your decisions could *actually* be laid out along polymorphic lines (i.e. the conditions map to which type the object is at execution time) then you can use inheritance to solve this instead. But if you really do just need multiple conditions like this, the conditional operator can be very helpful.